# Docker-compose up in different folders

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm new in docker containers and it seems that I don't understand something trivial, but I can't figure out what exactly.
I have docker-compose.yml file:

```
db:
  image: db21112017
  restart: always
  environment:
    POSTGRES_USER: admin
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
  ports:
    - 5432:5432
adminer:
  image: adminer
  restart: always
  links:
    - db
  ports:
    - 8080:8080
```

So, it depends only on 2 images. When I run it in  one folder on server it works fine, but when I simply copy this docker-compose.yml into another folder it gives "Internal Server Error". Also, when I change adminer image to another image 'adminer_tfidf', server runs like it run adminer image, like nothing changed.
What are possible reasons of that?

Before running docker-compose in another folder:

"docker ps":

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                          COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                  NAMES
```

"docker images":

```
  REPOSITORY              TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
db21112017              latest              9e8d832a1aea        8 months ago        286.9 MB
postgres                latest              4860bdf1a517        8 months ago        286.9 MB
adminer                 latest              1d3996dc2c87        8 months ago        58.78 MB
```

When I run docker-compose in new location "docker ps":

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                          COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
2c1223f51641        adminer                        "entrypoint.sh docker"   About an hour ago   Up 26 seconds       0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   askuzmina_adminer_1
1e5c8d3bcc8e        db21112017                     "docker-entrypoint.sh"   About an hour ago   Up 26 seconds       0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp   askuzmina_db_1
```

"docker images":

```
  REPOSITORY              TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
db21112017              latest              9e8d832a1aea        8 months ago        286.9 MB
postgres                latest              4860bdf1a517        8 months ago        286.9 MB
adminer                 latest              1d3996dc2c87        8 months ago        58.78 MB
```

Comment: Can you post your full docker-compose.yaml file?

Comment: This is full docker-compose.yml file

Comment: you sure you are not trying to run an instance of service while you already have it running in another terminal window? (can't use same host machine ports twice)

Comment: I think I don't.  I run 'docker-compose up' - it runs OK, I'm stopping it with 'Ctrl + C' and I don't see this containers when I look at containers with 'docker ps -a'. Then I make 'docker-compose up' of the same docker-compose.yml file in the another folder and have Internal Server Error.

Comment: What is the output of "docker images" and "docker ps"?

Comment: I see both of images:

db2              latest              9e8d832a1aea        8 months ago        

adminer                 latest              1d3996dc2c87        8 months ago        58.78 MB

And when I have Internal Server Error I see both of containers, and other unrelated containers: 2c1223f51641        adminer                        "entrypoint.sh docker"   56 minutes ago      Up 32 seconds       0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   askuzmina_adminer_1
1e5c8d3bcc8e  db2  "docker-entrypoint.sh"   56 minutes ago      Up 32 seconds       0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp   askuzmina_db_1

Comment: Are there only 2 images? What is the output of "docker ps"?

Comment: Could you please update your question with this info in a proper code formatting? It seems that you don't kill your previous containers before starting the new ones from another folder.